# Why Krull dimension of zero ring defined to be negative or it is just a convention?

Tags: ring-theory, convention, krull-dimension

[From wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_dimension) I have accrossed this claim "The Krull dimension of the zero ring is typically defined to be either ${\displaystyle -\infty } $ or ${\displaystyle -1} $. The zero ring is the only ring with a negative dimension " . Now my question here is :Why krull dimension of zero ring defined to be negative or just a convention ?

Comment: It should be $-\infty$. You want Krull dimension to be additive with respect to, say, products of varieties, and the product of the empty variety (the spectrum of the zero ring) with any variety is the empty variety.

Answer (score 4):

The least upper bound of the length of a chain of prime ideals in the zero ring is $-\infty$, since the zero ring has no prime ideals.